# offtopic question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

my question was off toped [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298576/eiπ-1-1iπ?noredirect=1#comment742859_298576](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298576/ei%CF%80-1-1i%CF%80?noredirect=1#comment742859_298576)

Now I clearly see no reason for this. Just like for having two distinct websites for this purpose.

1. It is not intuitive to feel that mathoverflow and math.stackexchane have different goal.
2. If possible, we should not read any rules to use a website
3. No reason for creating an extra entity website.
4. Add new tags if you want to distinct by goal.
5. Researcher mathematicians may find useful information on general abstract theory more often which may not even appear on mathoverflow.net

Thats things that seems obvious for me as for many-year user of stackoverflow.com. It is obvious such question will appear on constant basis according to 1,2,3. This mean need of an unnacessary moderation distractions. Also this always lead to acceptance positive dynamics in future anyway.

On the other hand, math.stackexchange accepts research questions as well which makes mathoverflow with all its nice design totally unnecessary, as for me.

So why it created, isn't  better for these websites to use single database right away and not flood productive people with totally unnecessary amount of distractions and time leakage?

What's the reason of such an unobviousities?

Comment: It was highly demotivate actually. Felt an impression of highly unfriendly community.

Comment: "we should not read any rules to use a website" I disagree. If you don't read the laws in your country you're going to get into great troubles.

Comment: @user202729, rules of using should be intuitive. People usually do not read software agreements. This is so because time is the most important thing in life.

Comment: Time is important for other people too. If you asked this on the correct site, users here would not need to take time to close/migrate it.

Comment: @Sergei People usually don't read the IKEA manual either, this doesn't change that those of us who do get to have more solid tables and beds. Complaining that "rules of using should be intuitive" is just not how things work.

Answer (score 16):

MathOverflow is geared toward professional mathematicians and their PhD students who seek answers to questions arising in their research. It is the preeminent internet clearinghouse for questions of this nature, and the community here would like to keep it that way and with that specific (high-level) focus.

Your question at the main site is not at that same high level, and so it was closed. MathOverflow is not a site where everyone can get an answer to their mathematics question. Our audience consists largely of busy professionals who don't expect and don't want to see the site overrun by questions at or below the undergraduate level; in fact they would likely leave in droves if that happened. They come here for a reason. This answers your 1. and 3. and I think 4. as well.

Generally speaking, you should always try first to understand the norms and expectations of any well-established internet community, spending perhaps a few days looking at their site and getting a sense of it. Rather than first angrily demanding to know why the community doesn't cater to your idea of what their site should be like. Thus your 2. is, to say it bluntly, ridiculous.

As for 5.: I honestly don't think you are in a position to judge what sorts of things a researcher in professionalized mathematics would find useful; sorry. The closure of your specific question suggests strongly that the community just doesn't view it as useful for the site. (As Nik Weaver said, it's not inherently a bad question; however, it's at the level of a student's first exposure to complex analysis, and thus not in the purview of topics we talk about.)

You can try asking your question at Mathematics StackExchange, but with Gerhard, I'd warn you that they too have site-specific standards, and you'd be well-advised to learn a little bit about them before asking questions there. That site has plenty of teaching professionals who can help with questions such as yours, but they generally want to see evidence that you've tried to think about your question before you asked, so that they can tailor an answer to your specific difficulty in understanding.